# What are 'typeless' DXGI texture formats in DirectX?

Tags: compression, gpu, directx, textures, directx-11

There are various texture formats in directX:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgiformat/ne-dxgiformat-dxgi_format

most are clear, but what are 'typeless' textures? for example, for BC6H, there are

```
DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_TYPELESS,
DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_UF16,
DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_SF16,
```

UF16 is unsigned float and SF16 is signed float and at least the encoder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/bc6h-format (maybe the decoder too?) seems to care about whether the format is signed or unsigned.

But what means 'typeless'? how is such a texture encoded and decoded?

Comment: see "Format Modifiers" "_TYPELESS" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgiformat/ne-dxgiformat-dxgi_format#format-modifiers

Comment: The doc states `When a typeless resource is bound to a shader, the application or shader must resolve the format type` how can a shader resolve a format type?

Comment: For example, when you create a Shader Resource View from a typeless texture, you can specify areas with different typed formats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_shader_resource_view_desc#remarks

Answer (score 1):

The "typeless" variants of DXGI formats are for special cases where you can change the way the data is interpreted. This allows you to create the resource (i.e. the actual "bag of bits") with the correct memory layout for the hardware (i.e. using a `_TYPELESS` format), and then you can create more than one view object using the specific type you want. This effectively lets you do the equivalent of a "C++ cast" in limited cases.

The most common cases for using typeless is dealing with depth/stencil formats, doing RGB swizzling a shader, and in DirectCompute implemented BC codecs. It's not a thing you use often, but when you do the option of loosening the type validation comes in handy.

For some examples of using typeless DXGI formats, see the [directx-sdk-samples](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples) GitHub and look at **AdaptiveTessellationCS40**, **BasicCompute11**, **CascadedShadowMaps11**, **MultithreadedRendering11**, and **VarianceShadows11**.

> For Xbox development, there are a few more cases where `_TYPELESS` comes in handy because it's a Unified Memory Access (UMA) architecture, but these bend the validation rules of 'stock' Direct3D.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-intro#strong-vs-weak-typing) and the [Direct3D 11.3 specification](https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/archive/D3D11_3_FunctionalSpec.htm).

Comment: but does that even make sense in the case of DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H? aren't the bits of a signed BC6h texture interpreted as an unsigned one complete gibberish and vice versa?

Comment: It could well be gibberish. Just like with C/C++ casting. The particular case here for BC6H is odd, but it's just a specific case. Most DXGI formats are grouped into 'typeless groups'.

Comment: Also note that this means hardware has to use the same physical video memory layout ``DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_UF16`` and ``DXGI_FORMAT_BC6H_SF16`` in terms of swizzling/tiling, stride, mip-map layout, etc. How you *interpret* that data is of course based on the actual choice of UF16 vs. SF16.